# Emacs printing: Error - unknown option "J"

Tags: emacs, printing, archlinux

I'm on an arch system (3.17.6-1-ARCH), using emacs 24.4.1

When I run a print command in emacs i get this error:

```
  Spooling... Done: /usr/bin/lp: Error - unknown option "J"
```

It seemes somewhere a "-J" is passed to lp, but I can't seem to figure out
    where.

The command works in a terminal, like:

```
  # lp fu.txt
```

Passing it a J flag reproduces the error:

```
  # lp -J
  lp: Error - unknown option "J".
```

google/ddg didn't spit out anything helpful about emacs and lp
    regarding the matter.

I'm setting the printer command like this in my .emacs config:

```
 (setq lpr-command "lp")
```

I tried giving it an empty `lpr-switches` variable, but I take
    from the documentation, that it only appends the switches.

If you have some clue about a solution or a hint to the origin
    of the problem, I would be grateful if you drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for `lpr-add-switches` reads:

> Non-nil means construct `-T` and `-J` options for the printer program.
>   These are made assuming that the program is `lpr`;
>   if you are using some other incompatible printer program,
>   this variable should be nil.

So `(setq lpr-add-switches nil)` should solve your problem.